# How to specify zero stack size for using handleMessage in omnet?

Tags: networking, omnet++

I am using **`handleMessage`** in my own **`csimplemodule`**. But during simulation it is asking for specifying the zero stack size or setting non-zero stack size.

So, how to specify the zero stack size in omnet++ since I don't intend to use Activity()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For earlier versions of OMNEt++ 3.x use

```
class yourClassName: public cSimpleModule{
public:
Module_Class_Members(yourClassName, cSimpleModule, 0);
}
```

But since version 4.0 it is deprecated. Instead use the below for setting the stack size to zero.

```
class yourClassName: public cSimpleModule{
public:
yourClassName() : cSimpleModule() {}
}
```

More details can be found [here.](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/group__MacrosReg.html#ga96dc1cfbc4574094cdd29d04c1a4d94a)

Your problem could be due to other issues like changing the handlemessage arguments from cMessage to other types. In which case you have to deal with it differently rather than changing the stack size, like the one mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/j1H4jfG6IjM).